# Ruby 'Mail' gem and corrupted HTML email

Tags: html, ruby, email, for-loop, rubygems

I am creating an html table and then sending it with the Mail gem and getting some unexpected html tags in the output like this:

```
< /tr>
DAY PRODUCT_CODE    USAGE_TYPE  LATE_ARRIVING_USAGE PERCENT
27-SEP-14   sdfgdfg sdfgdf  0.001   0.000%
27-SEP-14   sdfgdg  gfdgs   0.1 39  0.000%
27-SEP-14   sdfgdg  sdfgdsfg    0.001   0.000%
```

UPDATE: In the for loop below at 'HERE', if I place something like 'ANYTHING' after tr but inside the quotes, the left over tr at the top of the table just turns into 'ANYTHING' and the tr goes away. How does this happen??

I am not sure how that tr tag is getting there. Depending on how I concatenate the string some other ones show up like td style... but the way i'm doing now only has that extra tr tag. This is the for loop:

```
def get_file_as_html(filename)
begin

  data = ""
  if @has_report_header == "Y" && @report_header != ""
    data = "</br><table border =\"1\" style=\"border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;\"><tr>"
    data_row = @report_header.split(",")
    data_row.each_with_index do |elem,idx|
      str = elem.gsub("\"","").strip
      data += "<th style= 'align: center; width: 100;'>#{str}</th>"
    end
    data += "</tr>" # HERE --> "</tr>ANYTHING"
  end

  data_file = CSV.read(filename, { :col_sep => "\t" , :quote_char => '"' })
  #puts data_file
  data_file.each do |data_row|
    new_data_row = "<tr>"
    data_row.each_with_index do |elem,idx|
      new_data_row += "<td style= 'text-align: left;align:left; width: 100;'>#{elem}</td>"
    end
    new_data_row += "</tr>"
    data += new_data_row
  end

  table_footer = "</table></br></br>"
  data += table_footer

  return data

rescue Exception => e

  raise "PROBLEM_IN_HTML_REPORT_GENERATION"
end
end
```

I have ‘put’ the ‘data’ variable to the console and then into a fiddle and it looks perfect. When I send it the content_type is 'text/html’:

```
def send_attachment(filename,s3url,job_instance_id)
activity_id = get_activity_info(job_instance_id)
recipient_list = get_recipient_list()
my_body_is_ready = get_file_as_html(filename)

mail = Mail.deliver do
  to      'xxx@xxx.com'
  from    'xxx@xxx.com'
  subject @subject

  text_part do
    body 'This is plain text'
  end

  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body my_body_is_ready
  end
end

puts mail.to_s #=>

end
```

Anyone know what could be corrupting the message? Thanks,
Tim

Comment: FYI you don't need the `begin` and `end` in `get_file_as_html`. You can just do `def ... rescue ... end`.

Comment: ok. this does not help me though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem checks validity of HTML somehow.

The structure of table tag is:

```
<table>
  <th>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You misplaced `th` inside `tr` instead of `td` inside `th`. `th` states for table header, `tr` for table row.

Comment: err that made it even worse, i changed the tr's to th's and the th's to td's and the last column isn't even being populated.

Comment: Last column of header?

Comment: I noticed that in the @nd row of your example data there are 6 (!) columns: `27-SEP-14   sdfgdg  gfdgs   0.1 39  0.000%` (notice 0.1 followed by 39.)

Comment: the first column header is blank and then all the other headers are shifted one to the right. hmm i just looked at the source csv and there is no space between the .1 and 39. thanks again for the responses.

Comment: Just skip the first header element with `next if idx == 0` and you’ll have 5 column headers and everything should be rendered ok.